# Multiple animations on 1 imageview android

Tags: android, xml, animation, imageview

I have 2 animations which are already working,
i want to fade my train + tween my train on the same time.
If I execute 1 of these lines it works.
But if I try to execute both it, only 1 will work..
I really can't find a solution here.

Maybe you can help?

```
  final ImageView mytrain = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.train);
  final Animation traintween = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.treinanimation);
   final Animation trainfade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.trainfade);


  mytrain.startAnimation(trainfade);
 mytrain.startAnimation(trainntween);
```

I want mytrain to execute both animations..

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use the `AnimationSet` class:

```
AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);//false means don't share interpolators
s.addAnimation(traintween);
s.addAnimation(trainfad);
mytrain.startAnimation(s);
```

Comment: There is no `addAnimation()` method in `AnimationSet`

Comment: @konopko Yes their is. Since API level 1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html#addAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)

Comment: View.startAnimation(AnimationSet) is not possible. Why is this an accepted answer?

Comment: AnimationSet extends Animation, so startAnimation(Animation) can also be used with an AnimationSet.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use an `AnimationSet`, check out the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html). Just call `addAnimation()` for each Animation you want to play.

Comment: addAnimation(trainfade);
addAnimation(traintween);

public void addAnimation(Animation a) {
mytrain.startanimation(a); }

Is it like this?

Answer (score 4):

Can be done programatically using AnimatorSet class of android :

```
final AnimatorSet mAnimatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    mAnimatorSet.playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img_view,"scaleX",1,0.9f,0.9f,1.1f,1.1f,1),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img_view,"scaleY",1,0.9f,0.9f,1.1f,1.1f,1),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img_view,"rotation",0 ,-3 , -3, 3, -3, 3, -3,3,-3,3,-3,0)
        );

//define any animation you want,like above

mAnimatorSet.setDuration(2000); //set duration for animations
    mAnimatorSet.start();
```

this example will start all the 3 animation on the target view(imgView) at same time ,you can also use playSequentially .....

For complete example [check this out..](https://gagandroid.blogspot.in/2015/04/set-more-than-one-animation-on-view.html)

Answer (score 1):

here is the example of all animation in a single xml file...

this will help  you but first you should read the docs of AnimationSet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<scale android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="3.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="3.0" android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"  android:duration="5000" />
<set>
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromAlpha="0.2" android:toAlpha="1.0"     android:duration="3000" />
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="-360"
        android:toYScale="0.0" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="700" android:duration="4000" />
<!--        <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%" -->
<!--            android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="100%"     android:duration="3000" -->
</set>

</set>
```

Comment: it is important to consider using an interpolator to handle simultaneous animations on your namespaces

Answer (score 0):

you also can use the ImageSwitcher, i think this is better then AnimationSet in your case