# How to start an additional animation on a View without stopping its running animation?

Tags: android, xml, animation, imageview

I want an ImageView to be rotating all the time and make it bounce when the user clicks on it. 
I have both animations but I can't start the bouncing animation without stopping the rotating one.
**I don't want to start [both animations at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547621/multiple-animations-on-1-imageview-android).**
Here is  [what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqT5W.gif).
[AnimationSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html) doesn't seem to be what I need as the second animation has to start on click **while the first one is running**.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: use two `Animator`s, not two `Animation`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you pskink, [it works fine](http://i.giphy.com/WRsmA5XLjSOT6.gif)!
Here is the working code:

```
private ImageView rotating_image;
private AnimatorSet bounceAnimatorSet;
private ObjectAnimator rotationAnimator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    rotating_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rotating_image);
    if (rotating_image != null)
        rotating_image.setOnClickListener(this);
    setRotation();
    rotationAnimator.start();
    setBounceAnimators();
    ...
}

private void setRotation(){
    rotationAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rotating_image, "rotation",0,360);
    rotationAnimator.setDuration(4000);
    rotationAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    rotationAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
    rotationAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
}


private void setBounceAnimators(){
    bounceAnimatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    ObjectAnimator enlargeX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rotating_image, "scaleX",1,1.5f);
    enlargeX.setDuration(800);
    enlargeX.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    ObjectAnimator enlargeY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rotating_image, "scaleY",1,1.5f);
    enlargeY.setDuration(800);
    enlargeY.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    ObjectAnimator bounceX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rotating_image, "scaleX", 1.5f, 1);
    bounceX.setDuration(1000);
    bounceX.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());

    ObjectAnimator bounceY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rotating_image, "scaleY", 1.5f, 1);
    bounceY.setDuration(1000);
    bounceY.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());

    bounceAnimatorSet.play(enlargeX).with(enlargeY);
    bounceAnimatorSet.play(bounceY).with(bounceX).after(enlargeY);
}
```